# What patches do I need to play Battlefield 2?

Tags: pc, battlefield-2

I have a DVD copy of Battlefield 2 and don't know what patches I need to install first. The main ones are 1.41, 1.5, 1.51. I don't know if I need to just install 1.51 or what.

Last time I installed BF2 I couldn't get the 1.41 patch to work with my earlier version (1.2XXXXX something something).

If you're playing the game or have been, what patches do I need to install?

Answer (score 2):

Patch 1.5 combines all previous patches. As such, it is the only patch necessary. (Feb. 2012)

http://www.gamefront.com/files/14444947/Battlefield_2_Patch_v1_5

Comment: It also adds all addons for free.

Answer (score 1):

If you look online for 'battlefield 2 full patch', you can avoid doing multiple patches at one time. A full patch means that it includes all of the patches before that release so that any CD version of the game can be updated.

Note that full patches are considerably larger than normal patches, since it is multiple patches combined into one file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the patches already, you should update to 1.4, then 1.41, then 1.5, then 1.51. It is always best to install each patch separately, since if you miss a patch, it can cause a lot of trouble  getting into a game.

Answer (score 0):

Digging up some of the old games that I use-to love playing, I searched was searching for the patches, and I came across this page. Then reading the reply from " Lemmings19 ". I found It isn't exactly right.
Not all patches have the prior one installed inside of it.
Unless you go into the Patch information itself, and it actually says that it contains the prior patch in it, then don't assume that it does.

Found this...
" To update to patch 1.5, you will need to have version 1.41 installed. If you do not have patch 1.41 installed, you can download it at the link below"

This was taken from here....
https://help.ea.com/en/article/obtaining-the-latest-updates-for-battlefield-2/